# Converting UNIX Time in FQL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql, unix-timestamp

I have some basic FQL code, I would like to convert the timestamp to "g:i F jS Y" although the return is always "7:00 January 1st 1970".

I have used the same code before when querying MySQL.

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is this even best practice?

```
    $result = $facebook->api(array('method' => 'fql.query', 'query' => 'SELECT post_id,message,permalink,updated_time
                                                                        FROM stream
                                                                        WHERE source_id=' . $page_id . ' LIMIT 4'));




    foreach ($result as $post) {

        ?>



<tr class="feed"><td><p><?= $post['message'] ?> <br><br> <pink><?= date('d-m-Y', strtotime($post['updated_time']))?> </pink> <br> <a target="_blank" class="tweet-link" href="<?= $post['permalink'] ?>">View on Facebook</a></p></td></tr>


<?
```

Comment: What is the format of the `$post['updated_time']` value? seems like that may just not be a supported format of `strtotime()`. Because `strtotime()` will return `false` on failure, for any failure reason, and `(int)false == 0`, which 0 is the january date.

Comment: It's a UNIX timestamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `$post['updated_time']` is a valid unix timestamp, then just do this instead:

```
date('d-m-Y', $post['updated_time'])
```

No need to ask strtotime to reparse a timestamp, to a timestamp.